# How to create class from which I can use "get"?

Tags: python, class, attributes

In Python, I am trying to create a class that has attributes which I can "get" (sorry if this wording is not exactly correct).

Basically I am trying to define some class p which has attributes `var1` and `var2`. So then I can use `p.get("var1")` and `p.get("var2")` to get the values of these respective attributes. How can I define something like this?

Comment: You can use a `dict` instead

Comment: Define a `class` with a `get()` method.

Comment: do a tutorial on python classes and it will become immediately obvious what attributes and methods are, and how to use a method to return an attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class with `get()` method and check if the instance has the attribute with built-in `getattr()` method as following:

```
class MyClass:

  def get(self, property, default=None):
    return getattr(self, property, default)

  var1 = 'var1'
  var2 = 'var2'


myInstance = MyClass()

print(myInstance.get('var1'))
print(myInstance.get('var3', 'NonExisting Attribute'))
```

Here's a working repl.it project that I just created: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/OvalLiveMethod

---

You can also check if the instance has the attribute with `hasattr()` method:

```
class MyClass:

  def get(self, property, default=None):
    if hasattr(self, property):
      return getattr(self, property)
    else:
      return default
      # Or you can raise an exception here
```

Comment: I think it's also worth note that onecan also use `hasattr()` to check if the named attribute is exists.

Comment: @martineau The first version of the answer included `hasattr()` method but I edited it this way. I will update it to include this approach.

Comment: I think now it's even better (had already up-voted it).

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the improvement :) And also for the upvote, of course.

Answer (score 0):

#### For instance object

```py
class Test:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    
    def get(self, var):
        return eval('self.%s' % var)
    
t = Test()
a = t.get('a')
print(a) ## output: 1
```

#### For class object

```py
class Test:
    
    a = 1
    b = 2
    
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, var):
        return eval('cls.%s' % var)
    
a = Test.get('a')
print(a) # output: 1
```